# Indicate if a certain element exists through the use of Object.entries ()

Tags: javascript, loops

I need your help; I have an array of objects (called bookArr, below) as shown below.

bookArr is:

```js
[
  {part: 'Text', value: 'Geralt is a witcher, a stronger and more resilient individual than any human, who earns his living by killing those creatures that dismay even the most daring: demons, orcs, evil elves.' , id: 1},
  {part: 'Author', value: 'Andrzej Sapkowski', id: 2},
  {part: 'Image', value: 'book_imgrt5432tp.jpg', id: 3},
  {part: 'Title', value: "The guardian of the innocents. The Witcher. Vol. 1", id: 4}
]
```

Sometimes, for example, the author is not known; so once I have made a loop for each part, I want to know if the author (always taking the part into consideration) is missing because I need it in the if condition.

Therefore I did as below:

```js
if (Object.entries(results)[x][1].part == "Author") {
  document.getElementById("auth").innerHTML = Object.entries(results)[x][1].value;
} else if (Object.entries(results)[x][1].part == "") {
  do this....
}
```

I tried to use `Object.entries(results)[x][1].part == ""` but it doesn't work.

How can I solve my problem?

***EDIT***

If Author is missing, the entire row corresponding to Author is missing, therefore it does not exist

```js
{1: {…}, 2: {…}, 3: {…}, 4: {…}}
    1: {part: 'Text', value: 'Geralt is a witcher, a stronger and more resilient individual than any human, who earns his living by killing those creatures that dismay even the most daring: demons, orcs, evil elves.' , id: 1},
    2: {part: 'Author', value: 'Andrzej Sapkowski', id: 2},
    3:{part: 'Image', value: 'book_imgrt5432tp.jpg', id: 3},
    4: {part: 'Title', value: "The guardian of the innocents. The Witcher. Vol. 1", id: 4}
    [[Prototype]]: Object
```

***COMPLETE CODE:*** (*as I said, Author is not always present in the array (therefore the last instruction derives from it)*)

```js
while (x < Object.entries(results).length) {
    if (Object.entries(results)[x][1].part == "Title"){
        document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = Object.entries(results)[x][1].value;
        
    }
    else if (Object.entries(results)[x][1].part == "Text"){
        document.getElementById("txt1").innerHTML = Object.entries(results)[x][1].value;
    }
    else if (Object.entries(results)[x][1].part == "Image"){
        document.getElementById("img").src = Object.entries(results)[x][1].value;
    }
    else if (Object.entries(results)[x][1].part == "Author"){
        document.getElementById("auth").innerHTML = Object.entries(results)[x][1].value;;
    }
    else if(!Object.entries(results)[x][1].some(item => item.part == 'Author')) {
      console.log('yes')
      document.getElementById("auth").style.display="none";
    }
    
x++;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] if you haven't already (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: I'm afraid the information in the question is too fragmentary for us to help. You talk about an array, but then you're using `Object.entries`, which is for non-array objects (though it will work on an array, because arrays are also objects). Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder array of object

Comment: I know, but again, you wouldn't use `Object.entries`. We need more context. Are you doing this per entry? Or just once for the entire array? Or...?

Comment: why this? with the other fields it works correctly. I don't understand why Object.entries (results) [x] [1] .part == "" (just putting "") doesn't work

Comment: We can't tell you why that doesn't work -- you haven't told us what `results` is. Is it `bookArr`? Again: Please provide a [mre]. As for why not `Object.entries`: Because it makes no sense when you just want to access the `part` and `value` properties of the obejct.

Comment: But if `results` is `bookArr`, then `part == ""` doesn't work because `part` doesn't ever appear in your example with the value `""`. Your check won't check that **`value`** is missing or blank, and won't check that there is no element with `part: "Author"`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, right. If Author is missing, consequently the entire row corresponding to Author is missing. How can I define this?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, from the code the OP wrote, I think `results` is either an array of books (`[ [ {part: 'Text', ... }, {part: 'Author', ... }, ... ], [ ... ], [ ... ], ]`) or an object representing a list of books (`{ 1: [ {part: 'Text', ... }, {part: 'Author', ... }, ... ], 2: [ ... ] }`). But you are right, some more detailed information is required, if we do not want to keep guessing.

Comment: @a_l_e_x - I posted an answer showing how more than 15 minutes ago.

Comment: @a_l_e_x " _If Author is missing, the entire row corresponding to Author is missing, therefore it does not exist_ "; if my guess on what `results` is is correct, then when the author is missing `Object.entries(results)[x][1]` is the second item of the `bookArr` for the book X. In this case, even if the Author item is missing, there will still be a second item, whose `part` is `'Image'`, therefore you will never execute the `else if` block.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes but you did the example in case value is not known. If the author does not exist, the whole row does not have to exist, not just the value. Therefore the row corresponding to the Author (if this does not exist) must not exist (it is not inserted at all). I hope I have been clearer now. So I need to understand how to define if the row corresponding to Author does not exist.

Comment: @secan yes, however, I must create an empty div if the author does not exist (with do this in the code I mean this) even if I have not put it. So it's information that I absolutely need to keep

Comment: @a_l_e_x you can check if a book has an author with `bookArr.find(item => item.part == 'Author')`, which will return `undefined` if the book has no author. In the context of your code, it should be (if my assumptions are correct): `else if (Object.entries(results)[x].find(item => item.part == 'Author') == undefined) { ... }`

Comment: ... or, even better: `else if (!Object.entries(results)[x].some(item => item.part == 'Author')) { ... }`

Comment: no nothing, it still doesn't work

Comment: @a_l_e_x - Please read the answer carefully, the whole "row" (array element) not existing is covered by the first `if`.

Comment: @a_l_e_x, please share an example of how `results` looks like, otherwise we cannot go anywhere

Comment: @secan put on!!

Comment: @a_l_e_x, the code edits produce syntax error. You probably have to fix it and is this object the result?

Comment: @James no does not produce any errors

Comment: @a_l_e_x, feel like we are not using the  same thing. lol Click the run code snippet you will find that it `console` `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'",`

Comment: what i noticed seems that the code about that line is not being read correctly because it is being skipped. I'm not using just one element, I'm using a loop for all elements. Except that some do not have precisely the Author

Comment: @James put the complete code above, with the last statement not working

Comment: Now that you posted the entire code, I think two problem became evident: (1) your code will keep overwriting the HTML content (or the `src` attribute) of the same element, therefore you will always display _only_ the last book. (2) You are unnecessarily using `Object.entries()`, which returns a 2D array (`[ [key, value], [key, value], ... ]`), while for your use case `Object.values()` seems more appropriate. If I understood what you want to obtain, it should be something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/k0pw6t7h/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just wanna check the array contains the `part:Author` or not, just using `Array.find()` and you don't need to run the loop.

Updated: doesn't define the `x` and use `Object.entries(results)[1]` instead of `Object.entries(results)[x][1]`

```js
//No author
let results = [
 {part: 'Text', value: 'Geralt is a witcher, a stronger and more resilient individual than any human, who earns his living by killing those creatures that dismay even the most daring: demons, orcs, evil elves.' , id: 1},
  {part: 'Image', value: 'book_imgrt5432tp.jpg', id: 3},
  {part: 'Title', value: "The guardian of the innocents. The Witcher. Vol. 1", id: 4}
]

function check(){
let x = 0
if(!Object.entries(results)[1].find(item => item.part == 'Author')) {
console.log('no author')
      document.getElementById("idframe").style.display="none";
    }
while (x < Object.entries(results).length) {
    if (Object.entries(results)[x][1].part == "Title"){
        document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = Object.entries(results)[x][1].value;
        
    }
    else if (Object.entries(results)[x][1].part == "Text"){
        document.getElementById("txt1").innerHTML += Object.entries(results)[x][1].value;
    }
    else if (Object.entries(results)[x][1].part == "Image"){
        document.getElementById("img").src += Object.entries(results)[x][1].value;
    }
    else if (Object.entries(results)[x][1].part == "Author"){
        document.getElementById("auth").innerHTML += Object.entries(results)[x][1].value; 
        console.log(' have author')
    }
    
x++;
}
}
check()


//Without author
```

```html
<div id=img></div>
<div id=title></div>
<div id=txt1></div>
<div id=auth></div>
<div id=idframe></div>
```

Comment: I'll tell you another thing. If a book has the Author, both writings are displayed on the console. So that if statement is always read

Comment: @a_l_e_x, no it is not real-only statement, check again. It make the `auth` to be display: none

Comment: yes I understand what you mean. But unfortunately it seems that the program does this. There is nothing more can be done to solve the problem?

Comment: @a_l_e_x, I think so, we have been discussed more than 30 lines lol, and I think it should be absolutely work (working on my side). I try my best:(  Not sure why not working for you... It is the first time I spend so many time talkling with people about a specific topic. lol. Hope my answer help you in some context!

Comment: perfect thank you infinitely. As soon as I have the opportunity to vote for the answer I do it, because you have been very helpful and generous. I never stop thanking you. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @a_l_e_x, no problem at all. A good suggestion is next time you want to ask question on stackoverflow, please post the full code at the beginning or a producible example which is easier for us to help you. Also, I will be appreciated if you could upvote my answer or accept it if you find it helpful:)

Answer (score 0):

If I assume that the array represents just a single book, and you want to know if `value` is blank for the `part: "Author"` element or there is no such element, then `Object.entries` has no role to play here. Instead, use `find` to find out if there's an element with `part: "Author"` and, if there is, check that element to see if it has a non-blank `value`:

```
const authorElement = bookArr.find(({part}) => part === "Author");
if (!authorElement) {
    // There is no `part: "Author"` element at all
} else if (!authorElement.value) {
    // There is a `part: "Author"` element, but `value` is missing or blank
} else {
    // There's a `part: "Author"` element and it has a non-blank `value`
}
```

Live Example:

```js
function check(label, array) {
    const authorElement = array.find(({part}) => part === "Author");
    if (!authorElement) {
        // There is no `part: "Author"` element at all
        console.log(label, "no Author part");
    } else if (!authorElement.value) {
        // There is a `part: "Author"` element, but `value` is missing or blank
        console.log(label, "Author part has missing or blank value");
    } else {
        // There's a `part: "Author"` element and it has a non-blank `value`
        console.log(label, `Author part has value "${authorElement.value}"`);
    }
}

const bookArr = [
    {part: 'Text', value: 'Geralt is a witcher, a stronger and more resilient individual than any human, who earns his living by killing those creatures that dismay even the most daring: demons, orcs, evil elves.' , id: 1},
    {part: 'Author', value: 'Andrzej Sapkowski', id: 2},
    {part: 'Image', value: 'book_imgrt5432tp.jpg', id: 3},
    {part: 'Title', value: "The guardian of the innocents. The Witcher. Vol. 1", id: 4}
];
check("bookArr (array from the question):", bookArr);

const arrayWithoutElement = [
    {part: 'Text', value: 'Geralt is a witcher, a stronger and more resilient individual than any human, who earns his living by killing those creatures that dismay even the most daring: demons, orcs, evil elves.' , id: 1},
    {part: 'Image', value: 'book_imgrt5432tp.jpg', id: 3},
    {part: 'Title', value: "The guardian of the innocents. The Witcher. Vol. 1", id: 4}
];
check("arrayWithoutElement:", arrayWithoutElement);

const arrayWithMissingValue = [
    {part: 'Text', value: 'Geralt is a witcher, a stronger and more resilient individual than any human, who earns his living by killing those creatures that dismay even the most daring: demons, orcs, evil elves.' , id: 1},
    {part: 'Author', id: 2},
    {part: 'Image', value: 'book_imgrt5432tp.jpg', id: 3},
    {part: 'Title', value: "The guardian of the innocents. The Witcher. Vol. 1", id: 4}
];
check("arrayWithMissingValue:", arrayWithMissingValue);

const arrayWithBlankValue = [
    {part: 'Text', value: 'Geralt is a witcher, a stronger and more resilient individual than any human, who earns his living by killing those creatures that dismay even the most daring: demons, orcs, evil elves.' , id: 1},
    {part: 'Author', value: '', id: 2},
    {part: 'Image', value: 'book_imgrt5432tp.jpg', id: 3},
    {part: 'Title', value: "The guardian of the innocents. The Witcher. Vol. 1", id: 4}
];
check("arrayWithMissingValue:", arrayWithBlankValue);
```